# How to write unit tests for methods thsat echo instead of return (e.g., AJAX call handlers)

Tags: ajax, testing

There are several methods in CiviCRM that just print their output directly to the buffer and then exit, because they're just sending an HTML snippet or other response for an AJAX call. For example, CRM_Event_Cart_Page_CheckoutAJAX::add_participant_to_cart().

What are best practices for (or existing examples of) unit tests that cover such methods?  I could, I suppose, use ob functions to capture the output, but then I'd need an external library to parse and test the HTML. Are there better ways, and are there examples already in place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allan - I have tended to try to refactor the AJAX functions such that they call a more testable function & test that - this generally improves the code....

There are a few examples that test the calls directly - see classes like

CRM_Contact_Page_AjaxTest
CRM_Custom_Page_AJAXTest
CRM_Financial_Page_AjaxTest
CRM_Group_Page_AjaxTest

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit out of date on the current status of the civi test framework, but if WebTests are still available I would do this as a WebTest.
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Setting+yourself+up+to+work+with+Selenium+tests

Include a line that waits for some element you are expecting to appear, then test its value using the webtest api.

Comment: It looks like they do still exist. See e.g. https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/tests/phpunit/WebTest/Contact/AddTest.php, and it looks like there's a utility function you can use $this->waitForAjaxContent().

Comment: Webtests run - but they are of limited value as they are too slow & unreliable to run as part of CI :-(